# ARM template to add custom hostname to a set of websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to use this Azure Resource Manager template code snippet to add a custom domain to set of webapps.  The web apps are being created correctly, as is the traffic manager profile.  However, the ARM template is failing when adding the custom hostnames.  Note that I'm using a variable parameter that is passed into the template to create the websites.

```js
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app,linux,container",
      "location": "[parameters('webAppLocations')[copyIndex()]]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('webAppLocations'))]",
        "name": "siteCopy"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "farmCopy"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "appsettings",
          "type": "config",
          "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "Application settings"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publishingUsername": "[variables('publishingUsername')]",
            "DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME": "[parameters('dockerImageName')]"
          }
        }
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))), '-', copyIndex())]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-', copyIndex()))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex(), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex(), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]"
      ]
    }
```

```js
2018-03-20T23:50:20.7707394Z ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex(), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]' at line '1' and column '2892' is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.
2018-03-20T23:50:20.7723109Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

Note that the copyIndex() works fine for the website names elsewhere in the template.  So why isn't it working for the "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings" section?  I'm stumped.

Here are the parameters.  Note the webAppLocations parameter which is an array.

```js
"parameters": {
    "webAppNamePrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "dockerImageName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of docker image to use"
      }
    },
    "farmSkuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Describes plan's pricing tier and capacity. Check details at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/"
      }
    },
    "environmentType": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "qa",
        "prod"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Environment type name"
      }
    },
    "webAppLocations": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "trafficManagerPrefix": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "customHostname": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
          "description": "The custom hostname that you wish to add."
      }
    }    
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never really place anything after `resources` property, not because it breaks the template, but because its much harder to look at it. in your case you placed `Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings` outside of resources.

```
{
    "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "app,linux,container",
    "location": "[parameters('webAppLocations')[copyIndex()]]",
    "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
    "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('webAppLocations'))]",
        "name": "siteCopy"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "farmCopy"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))), '-', copyIndex())]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]"
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-', copyIndex()))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "appsettings",
            "type": "config",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat(parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex())]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "displayName": "Application settings"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publishingUsername": "[variables('publishingUsername')]",
                "DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME": "[parameters('dockerImageName')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "hostnameBindings",
            "name": "[parameters('customHostname')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {},
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',parameters('webAppNamePrefix'), '-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id), '-site-', copyIndex(), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks good 4c74356b41 (that's a mouthful to say!). 
Unfortunately I've now got another error (that I think I've moved forward). The error is:
`##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'domain-jmfjo3qd53vd2-site-0' at line '0' and column '0' is not valid: The resource identificator 'Microsoft.Web/sites/prefix-jmfjo3qd53vd2-site-0/host.domain.com' is malformed. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#reference for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'`  
Any idea why that is happening? thanks

Comment: try this variant? i forgot to fix the resource type\name. my bad.

Comment: thanks.  I tried it again.
unfortunately still not quite right I'm afraid. Now error reads as 
` ##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'host.domain.com' at line '0' and column '0' is not valid: The resource identificator 'Microsoft.Web/sites/domain-jmfjo3qd53vd2-site-0/host.domain.com' is malformed`

Comment: ok, so probably something is wrong with the name. try creating the same resources using the portal

Comment: ok. name of the webapp created, or name of the custom domain?

Comment: both, like you are trying to do with the template

Comment: mmm- this is weird
I think I managed to move forward, but I've hit another error. Unfortunately, I can't paste the full error.  But the summary is this: 
'"Message": "A CNAME record pointing from host.domain.com to domain-jmfjo3qd53vd2-site-0.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.host.domain.com to awverify.domain-jmfjo3qd53vd2-site-0.azurewebsites.net was not found either."'
I'll add some more below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167356/discussion-between-ossentoo-and-4c74356b41).